# Как правильно закрыть объект ms word в OleContainer

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Мой MS Word имеет СОМ нештатную надстройку (DIRECTUM), которая "прихватывает" открытый файл своим процессом. Не знаю зачем.
Если закрывать файл в оболочке Word, то все будет нормально. 
Если рабочий файл открыть в `OleContainer`:

```
oc1.CreateObjectFromFile(LMDLabel1.Caption,false);
```

затем

```
oc1.Close;
oc1.DestroyObject;
```

то процесс надстройки не завершается. После завершения моей программы выдается сообщение об ошибке COM и в каталоге остается файл с тильдой.
Что нужно сделать, чтобы файл в `OleContainer` закрывался корректно как в оболочке Word?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел [пример](http://www.delphi-club.ru/delphi/delphi_and_word_ole_automation.html), может поможет:

```
var
  SaveChanges: OLEVariant;
  OriginalFormat: OLEVariant;
  RouteDocument: OLEVariant;
begin
  SaveChanges := wdDoNotSaveChanges;
  OriginalFormat := unAssigned;
  RouteDocument := unAssigned;
  oc1.Quit(SaveChanges, OriginalFormat, RouteDocument);
end;
```